# How to set wallpaper from imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview, wallpaper, android-gridview

I am still can't find the way to set wallpaper that the image getting from ImageView.
Anyone can show me the way to set phone wallpaper from android ImageView?

Here is my code:

## ImageView Layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:contentDescription="My Wallpaper"
    android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:saveEnabled="true"
    />
```

## Activity on Image View

Please noted that the image that showing in `FullImageActivity` is getting from image `GridView` after user clicked on item.

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

    // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
}
}
```

I want to set wallpaper from image in above activity after user touch on screen i will popup to ask user whether they want to set it as wallpaper or not.

Comment: Yes, i think @Abdul code is enought to set your image as Wallpaper

Comment: dear SpK, I added but it's couldn't work :(

Comment: Try my answer. With your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted my code whatever i'm using in my application. I've also take the image from `GridView` and, when anyone of the image is being selected. That'll set as wallpaper.

But, my code seems just different. I never used any `ImageView`

**MainActivity.this**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            ImageAdapter i = (ImageAdapter)parent.getAdapter();                
            Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),(int)i.getItemId(position));

            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

            try {
                myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(mBitmap);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wallpaper set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error setting wallpaper", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return mFullSizeIds[position];
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null) {  
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 250));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.wallpaper1t, 
            R.drawable.wallpaper2t, 
            R.drawable.wallpaper3t, 
            R.drawable.wallpaper4t, 
            R.drawable.wallpaper5t, 
            R.drawable.wallpaper6t, 
            R.drawable.wallpaper7t, 
            R.drawable.wallpaper8t
    };

    private Integer[] mFullSizeIds = {
            R.drawable.wallpaper1, 
            R.drawable.wallpaper2, 
            R.drawable.wallpaper3, 
            R.drawable.wallpaper4, 
            R.drawable.wallpaper5, 
            R.drawable.wallpaper6, 
            R.drawable.wallpaper7, 
            R.drawable.wallpaper8
    };
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Maybe, this can be helps you lot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a bitmap then set it as the wallpaper

```
            Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), IMAGE_ID);
            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                    .getInstance(getApplicationContext());

            try {
                myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(mBitmap);
                Toast.makeText(SetWallPaper.this, "Wallpaper set",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(SetWallPaper.this,
                        "Error setting wallpaper", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
```

Where IMAGE_ID is the resource ID of your drawable, e.g. R.drawable.imagename

Comment: So, I convert like this:  Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.full_image_view); let me try

Comment: dear abdul, I added but it's couldn't work. then i use this one also not work. Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);

Comment: Dear Abdul, I success already..thank you for your code.it's help me alot :)

Comment: @SopheakVirak what did you put instead of "imageID" I need it ??

Comment: Jouni , you want set wallpapaer from you drawable folder then R.drawable.imagename. is imageID